# In filter gridview_page index is changing is not working on the bases of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Filtering the gridview on the bases of dropdown and the gridview is dispaly accordingly, but when I press on the next index of gridview than whole data is bound, and I Cann't find the desire output..also I want show the grid on page load..
Here is code of binding gridview

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table_student  ", con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

and code on page index of gridview is

```
 GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindgrid();
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are doing the following:

```
AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" // this can be any number you want to show
OnPage...Event="nameofevent"
```

And in the event you are doing the same.

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
bindgrid();
```

Comment: ok,but on PAGE_load I bind the grid same, and the same problem occure on next even of page after removing the bindgrid function

Comment: So bind the grid in if(!IsPostBack) as this will bind the grid on first time page load and next time, events will do the work.